# Failures: No manifest was fetched. with Nuxt/pwa module 2.6.0

Tags: progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js

currently using "@nuxtjs/pwa": "2.6.0" having the issue manifest not registering on lighthouse analysis, service worker also taking time.
specific lighthouse error Failures: No manifest was fetched.

[image]

I can help with code also if needed!!

My nuxt.config.js

```
 build: {
    publicPath: cdn.com
 },
 modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa'
 ],
 manifest: {
    name: 'name',
    description: "Desc",
    theme_color: '#607D8B',
    short_name: 'shortname'
 },
```

Using Docker deployer. upload the content of .nuxt/dist/client directory to your CDN ([PublicPath Docs Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#publicpath))

Comment: not enough info. where\how u deploy and your nuxt cofnig

Comment: @Aldarund updated my post. I can give you live URL also

Comment: so do u have a manifest.****.json file in .nuxt/dist/client ?

Comment: Yes we have. That also uploaded at CDN. Live site link desidime.com/games

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/QosOGmx.png here report for your url. Also you have a problem that start_url must be same origin as document, thats the only error  there

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you have to wrap manifest object into pwa: https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/manifest

Try this:

```
// Nuxt config
pwa: {
  manifest: {
    name: 'name',
    description: "Desc",
    theme_color: '#607D8B',
    short_name: 'shortname'
  }
}
```